# Tenancy for laravel - Not detecting the tenants database

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, multi-tenant

I am using this package https://tenancyforlaravel.com/ and I already setup one test tenant `tenant1`. When I login to its domain `tenant1.localhost:8000/login`, it says

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'academymanager.users' doesn't exist
```

I think it didn't detect the tenants database since its using my main database.
My main db is `academymanager` and the tenants db is `academymanager_tenant1`. Does naming convention affects it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you are using laravel fortify. If you do just add this InitializeTenancyByDomain::class into the fortify config middleware